# How to play music using MusicPlayService

Tags: java, android, service, media-player

I'm a student and just started learning java and android(currently using android studio). I have been following a tutorial with video streaming and music streaming. but I'm currently following with music streaming.

Code is fine but the problem is It won't stream the music. Also there's no error showing that I missed something or anything in the program. It is running on the emulator but it just wont play the music.

Below is my code for the MainActivity.java:

```
package com.name.package.yb;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnPlayStop;
    private boolean boolMusicPlaying = false;
    Intent myService;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try{
            myService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MusicPlayService.class);
            initViews();
            setListeners();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void initViews() {
        btnPlayStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        btnPlayStop.setText("Stream Music");
    }

    private void setListeners() {
        btnPlayStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnPlayStopClick();
            }
        });
    }

    private void btnPlayStopClick() {
        if (!boolMusicPlaying) {
            btnPlayStop.setText("Pause Streaming");
            playAudio();
            boolMusicPlaying = true;
        } else {
            if(boolMusicPlaying){
                btnPlayStop.setText("Play Stream");
                stopPlayService();
                boolMusicPlaying = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void stopPlayService() {
        try {
            stopService(myService);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        boolMusicPlaying = false;
    }

    private void playAudio() {
        try {
            startService(myService);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And My Service named MusicPlayService.java (I want to play the music in background like the music player on phone):

```
package com.name.package.yb;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;


public class MusicPlayService extends Service  {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    private static final String AUDIO_STRING = "http://musicsite.streammusic.com/file";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        //mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        //mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(100,100);
        //mediaPlayer.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(AUDIO_STRING);
                // Prepare mediaplayer
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                mediaPlayer.start();

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

P.S apk was succefully installed in the emulator and button is clickable. It just wont' play the music.

Comment: can you share manifest.xml code and did you gave internet permissions ?

Comment: yes: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />,     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> I have this one on my manifest file but no service

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, perhaps do you add service to your Manifest?

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MusicPlayService" />
```

[

Welcome to programming in Android, the best way to debug Android Code is by adding logs to your codes.  You can use Log.d, Log.e etc to print the value of the variable pass by methods.

]

Comment: Oops. nope. I haven't. By the way, the android:name="" is that the name of my service class?

Comment: Yes indeed.  I hope it helps

Comment: still wont work even I already added <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MusicPlayService" />.

Comment: @Harix You must declare service in the Manifest or else it won't run the service.  Since it is still not running, I guess you miss some declaration somewhere, I will try to look through again.

Comment: <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MusicPlayService" /> that is my manifest service. Thanks for your help in advance anyways. I'm also looking for some answers in google docs that could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

**1: the code**

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("http://vprbbc.streamguys.net:80/vprbbc24.mp3"));
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: anywhere.. may be on click listener or oncreate

Comment: i have added it on my onCreate: @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
         mediaPlayer.setVolume(100,100);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("http://musicsite.streammusic.com/file"));
        //mediaPlayer.reset();
    }  But still not working. I only get an error: cannot find symbol variable Uri, perhaps I need to put import something?

Comment: Please open link in browser .. it show's The file you requested could not be found.

Comment: if there is no file how can it  be streamed.. ?

Comment: The link is working fine I'm able to play it. Ps I edited the original link (I don't own it-its from my brother's work file from radio).

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(AUDIO_STRING);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
```

You also need to permission for INTERNET if you play music online or READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE if you play music from memory.